# Jquery/Jquery UI not loading?

Tags: jquery

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why Jquery won't load. It and Jquery UI are being accessed off Google API so it should work fine, but I get 'jquery is undefined' messages.

All I can figure is it's a conflict with some of the other scripts?

Source it and see if you can help out. Thanks.

http://marianoagency.com/intranet/trial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- JS Functions
```

is not valid javascript in functions.js

try `//    <!-- JS Functions`

Comment: Sometimes when you've been looking at something too long you just overlook the easy stuff. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

In your http://marianoagency.com/intranet/scripts/functions.js file you have:

```
<!-- JS Functions

function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0
  eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
  if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
}

function window(page,tl,wd,ht) {
OpenWin = this.open(page, tl, "toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width="+wd+",height="+ht);
}

function window2(page) {
OpenWin = this.open(page, "CtrlWindow", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=500,height=300");
}

//-->
```

Those aren't legal JavaScript comment tags. Use `/*` and `*/` instead if you want to comment out the entire block of code, or `//` per line.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Joe Tuskan's answer, you have a very suspicious piece of code here:

```
function window(page,tl,wd,ht) {
OpenWin = this.open(page, tl, "toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,width="+wd+",height="+ht);
}
```

Calling a function `window` is a really bad idea, because it will conflict with the global `window` object. It isn't strictly speaking a reserved word in the grammatical sense, but it might as well be.

Answer (score 0):

You have the `jQuery` loading after the plugin/personal scripts.

also here is a common fallback if Google fails:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src=\"http://trackmyclosing.net/ci/plugins/js/jquery-1.7.2.js\" type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why would he get "jquery is undefined" if his link to jQuery on Google is fine? If the problem was the order of the scripts he'd get a different error.

Comment: if he's using `jQuery('#id')` before it is loaded, wouldn't it be `undefined`?